# Logging in returns undefined peekState error

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

We have a login screen that stays on screen in an Android Nativescript Angular app for many hours, and is used by employees to clock into work and clock out. Intermittently when someone enters their login credentials a "Cannot read property 'peekState' of undefined" error is returned instead of logging them in.

The only similar reference I found was someone who was using router-outlet instead of page-router-outlet tkMainContent, but that is not our problem. Any ideas on how to correct this problem?

Comment: It's a JavaScript error in your code itself. You are trying to access property named peekState while the source is undefined. It's purely up to your code, so without a sample it's hard to guess any further.

Comment: @Manoj. I don't know what peekState is and we certainly don't ever use it in any code that we've written. It has to be something implicitly invoked by the framework.

Comment: In that case your issue must be related, because within Angular framework peekState is used in location strategy class. So it could be something with your routing, please share a sample Playground where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: The problem is the error is definitely intermittent. I am not able to reproduce it when I try, but it is caught by the logger and displayed to the user in a dialog window.

Comment: @Manoj: I don't find any reference to peekState in the Angular documentation, even on the LocationStrategy page. Can you send me a link to where it is documented?

Comment: It did not have to be documented, it's some [internal code](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.ts#L52). I'm not really sure but you may be accessing some routing related stuffs too early which might be causing the issue.